# How to Set Value for Field in winforms c# using Reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, setvalue

My Project have this:

```
private clsDTO_Error DTO_Error; --> Have PropertyName = ID
private clsDTO_Right DTO_Right;
FieldInfo f = this.GetType().GetField(DTO_Error, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This example is working properly

> DTO_Right.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).SetValue(DTO_Right, "OK", null);

or

> f.FieldType.GetProperty("ID").SetValue(DTO_Error,"OK",null);

I have a problem in this:

> f.FieldType.GetProperty("ID").SetValue(f.FieldType,"ERROR",null);

Any ideas for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do note that properties are not the same as fields, reflection cares about this distinction. You can simply apply the same code for `DTO_Error` as you have done for `DTO_Right` (so far as I can see from the code above; which is: get the type of `DTO_Error`, find the property, call `SetValue` on that property providing the `DTO_Error` instance and the property value. Or, and not to throw spanners into works here, use the DLR: `dynamic errorDto = (dynamic)DTO_Error; errorDto.ID = value;`

Comment: I don't know what field i'll call next, so I use FieldInfo. And DTO_Right i know exactly

Comment: ----------------
I do not quite get it
I have many repeat action must be used this way

Comment: why not use standard data binding?

Comment: Data binding? How to use it?

Comment: @TrươngLong a quick google reveals much. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe Databinding isn't what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my answer that I use `Directionary`

```
private Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
//Add this in Form Load
myDictionary.Add("DTO_Error", DTO_Error);
//Set Value
PropertyInField.SetValue(myDictionary[DTO_Error], "OK", null);
```

Comment: [Data binding MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

f.FieldType.GetProperty("ID").SetValue(this,"ERROR",null);

Comment: Error too!!! :(

`'f.FieldType.GetProperty("ID").SetValue(this,"Test",null)' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' void {System.Reflection.TargetException}`